How to create a 3d ndarray from 1d ndarrays
I'd like to create a 3d ndarray to represent co-ordinates from three 1d ndarrays similar to how numpy's meshgrid works. e.g. what is the rust equivalent for python's:
a = np.array(
    np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(-1, 1, 50),
        np.linspace(-1, 1, 50),
        np.linspace(-1, 1, 50),
        indexing="ij"
    )
)


While it's not built in, we can write our own. While seemingly generic over all dimensions, it will only work up to 5 input arrays, as Dim<[Ix; 6]> is the largest dimensionality that implements Dimension. (Beyond that, we'd need to allocate dynamic arrays and/or use IxDyn.)
use ndarray::{prelude::*, Data, Ix, OwnedRepr, RawData};
use num_traits::Zero;

enum Indexing {
    Ij,
    Xy,
}

fn meshgrid<S, const N: usize>(
    arrs: [ArrayBase<S, Ix1>; N],
    indexing: Indexing,
) -> ArrayBase<
    OwnedRepr<<S as RawData>::Elem>,
    <Dim<[Ix; N]> as Dimension>::Larger,
>
where
    S: Data + RawData + Clone,
    <S as ndarray::RawData>::Elem: Clone,
    Dim<[Ix; N]>: Dimension,
    <Dim<[Ix; N]> as Dimension>::Larger: Dimension + Zero,
{
    let mut out_shape = <Dim<[Ix; N]> as Dimension>::Larger::zero();
    for (i, dim) in out_shape.as_array_view_mut().iter_mut().enumerate() {
        *dim = if i == 0 { N } else { arrs[i - 1].len() };
    }

    let mut out_arrs = Array::uninit(out_shape);

    for (i, (mut out_arr, in_arr)) in
        out_arrs.outer_iter_mut().zip(&arrs).enumerate()
    {
        for lane in out_arr.view_mut().lanes_mut(Axis(i)) {
            in_arr.assign_to(lane);
        }
    }

    if matches!(indexing, Indexing::Xy) && N > 1 {
        out_arrs.swap_axes(N - 1, N - 2);
    }

    unsafe { out_arrs.assume_init() }
}

fn main() {
    let arr1 = Array1::linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 2);
    let arr2 = Array1::linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 3);
    let arr3 = Array1::linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 4);
    let grid = meshgrid([arr1, arr2, arr3], Indexing::Ij);

    println!("{grid:?}");
}

[[[[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
   [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
   [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]],

  [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]],


 [[[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]],

  [[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0],
   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]],


 [[[-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0],
   [-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0],
   [-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0]],

  [[-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0],
   [-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0],
   [-1.0, -0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333326, 1.0]]]], shape=[3, 2, 3, 4], strides=[24, 12, 4, 1], layout=Cc (0x5), const ndim=4


Thanks, any idea why this isn't part of ndarray already? seems like an odd thing to leave out considering how popular meshgrid is for numpy and that (while your solution is significantly more elegant than what I would have come up with) it doesn't seem to be a terribly complex thing to implement.
P.S. if you haven't / aren't planning to make a pull request for this feature to ndarray do you mind if I do so (I would of course give you full credit and link to this question)?

I don't care about credit. Feel free to make this PR yourself.

I did a bit more testing and found that your meshgrid function is replicating the output the same number of times as the number of dimensions. E.g. meshgrid for 3d outputs a 4d array containing three identical 3d arrays e.g.:

`let n = 3;
let max = 1.0;
let min = -1.0;

let grid = meshgrid(
    [
        nd::Array::linspace(min, max, n),
        nd::Array::linspace(min, max, n),
        nd::Array::zeros(n),
    ],
    Indexing::Ij
);

println!("{:#?}", grid.slice(nd::s![.., .., .., 0]));
println!("==========================================================");
println!("{:#?}", grid.slice(nd::s![.., .., .., 1]));
println!("==========================================================");
println!("{:#?}", grid.slice(nd::s![.., .., .., 2]));`


Could you please let me know how I can fix this? I expect it relates to this line: let mut out_shape = <Dim<[Ix; N]> as Dimension>::Larger::zero(); but to be honest I'm not as well acquainted with the ndarray traits as you
